# How to add multiple array values in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

It gives me an error while submitting multiple values in Database
**Error: IndexOutofBond**

```
<form action="emp/forsubmit" method=" post">
   <input id="emp[0].name" name="emp[0].name"  type="text"/>
   <input id="emp[0].lastname" name="emp[0].lastname"  type="text"/>
<input id="emp[1].name" name="emp[1].name"  type="text"/>
<input id="emp[1].lastname" name="emp[1].lastname"  type="text"/>
</form>
```

I am using **MongoDb** as Db

Controller Source Code :

```
def update(){

if(empInstance.getEmp_history() == null || empInstance.getEmp_history().size() == 0) {
            empInstance.setEmp_history(new ArrayList<EmpHistory>());
            empInstance.getEmp_history().add(new EmploymentHistory());
        }
 empInstance.properties = params
}
```

Comment: How is it different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698011/how-to-add-array-object-in-grails-2-2-2) question that was posted yesterday?

Comment: both form are same....in yesterday form i trying to submit directly second object of an array "emp[1]" .. an this time i am trying to submit both object at same time "emp[0] and emp[1] ".. but still it gives me same error

Comment: @user2446714: submitting a form will NOT cause a database error. You should show some controller code.

Comment: Wtf is this? `name=id="..."`

Answer (score 2):

Use the same name attribute value:

```
First: <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
First: <input type="text" name="lastname"/>

Second: <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
Second: <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
```

And they will be processed as an array by grails when form has been submitted, and then populate your domain object for every loop round :

```
params.firstname.eachWithIndex { value, index ->
     // use index to access the values in other array
     // params.lastname[index]
     def mydomain = new MyDomain()
     mydomain.firstname = value
     mydomain.lastname  = params.lastname[index]
     mydomain.save()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same name attribute value:

```
First: <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
First: <input type="text" name="lastname"/>

Second: <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
Second: <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
```

And the code below work even the element is only one and they will be processed as an array by grails when form has been submitted, and then populate your domain object for every loop round :

```
def firstName = params.list('firstname')   
def lastName = params.list('lastname') 
firstName.eachWithIndex { value, index ->
     // use index to access the values in other array
     // params.lastname[index]
     def mydomain = new MyDomain()
     mydomain.firstname = value
     mydomain.lastname  = lastName[index]
     mydomain.save()
}
```